# Spring Boot - Log4j2 - 2 files are generated

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am using Log4j2 and Spring Boot (1.2.4). Following the documentation (and the log4j2-file.xml as example in spring-boot.jar), here is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="Logs" fileName="${sys:LOG_FILE}" append="false">
    ...

<Logger level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="Logs"/>
 </Logger>
```

In application.properties file :
    logging.file: /var/tmp/logs/mylog.log

As a result, 2 files are generated :

- One file named *${sys:LOG_FILE}* which remains empty
- One file /var/tmp/logs/mylog.log properly filled

I do not understand why the file *${sys:LOG_FILE}* is generated.

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using version 1.2.5.RELEASE of Spring Boot (including the starter parent) and I'm seeing the same issue.

My assumption is that Log4j2 tries to initalize the file before Spring Boot loaded the configuration, resulting in an empty file called ${sys:LOG_FILE} or ${sys (on Windows).

One way of avoiding this is to just set the system property (-DLOG_FILE=/var/tmp/logs/mylog.log) and remove logger.file from your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have let down log4j2 to use logback which is well integrated in spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

It seem log4j2.xml is loaded and log file is created before application.properties being loaded. One way to fix this is to change the name of log4j2.xml to something else, for example `log4j2-example.xml` to present auto loading and then add the following line into application.properties:

```
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-example.xml
```

This will ensure the LOG_PATH are loaded before creating logger.

Answer (score 0):

logging.file is just used for default logger configured by spring only.
In this case, your LOG_FILE must be passed into system variable before execute the jar by -DLOG_FILE=/location/of/log.file